# Damaged wheel rims

Tags: wheels

[image][image]

I bought this bike and has matching dents in both wheels however with being new to bikes I thought it was normal. When I found out it wasn't the shop is refusing liability. But you can clearly see on this image which sales rep sent day before I bought the bike. He is saying he can't see any damage? Am I right that you can see this?

Comment: I can see a pale patch in the pics, just left of the valve, but it looks like a reflection of the white paint on the fork.  I do not see a dent.

Comment: If the bike is unsuitable for purpose then you should be able to return it for a full refund.  Depends what the consumer protection laws are in your country, and how much time has passed.  If you've owned it for months then you might be unable to return it.

Comment: Thinking more - this might be a question for legal.stackexchange.com because its about a sale/return of a faulty product.  If you were asking how to fix it then that would be on-topic for this site.

Comment: I can't see anything.  We need a better picture.

Comment: We need a some marking to show where the damage is supposed to be.

Comment: above the reflection of the fork leg, looks like rim is possibly flat spotted a bit, but very hard to tell from this image

Comment: I'd say: Forget about it. It's not worth the stress. Maybe you got a kink in your rim, but what's the fuzz? Rims have been a regular replacement part since the invention of rim brakes, and small dents (small enough that we have real hard trouble seeing what you mean, I for one have not found your dents yet) are not enough to make them fail or perform worse in any kind of way. Especially not with disk brakes (which you got). If you are fuzzing about this, you are fuzzing about a purely aesthetic thing... Just consider what will happen to your bike when you slip on ice in winter!

Comment: @cmaster By the way, since I've seen you use this twice, "fuzz" means soft fur; you mean "fuss".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you very much. I'm not a native speaker, and didn't realize that these two were actually two different words. I really appreciate your correction :-)

Answer (score 1):

There’s an inconsistent shadow between the rim and the tire, immediately left of the valve stem. It might be something or nothing; a gap or just a shadow.

If you’ve shown the photo alongside the wheel to the sales rep already I don’t know what would change his mind. He might simply not see it in the photo, I see a maybe and others here see nothing.  If you’re convinced of it I guess you need to speak to the most senior person you can at the shop.

As Criggie suggests, maybe better in the legal.SE site, someone there might know better how to proceed.